# how many decimal digits does float supports?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, precision

```
int main(){
    int s=200;
    printf("%.12f",s/3.0);
}
```

How this program is giving output 66.666666666667 even though float can support up to only 6-7 decimal places?

Meanwhile,

```
int main(){ 
    float s=200; 
    printf("%.12f",s/3);
}
```

gives 66.666664123535.

please help?

Comment: Who tells you that float only supports 6~7 decimal places? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: BTW you do not printf `float` only `double`

Answer (score 2):

There *isn't any* `float` in the first program. `%f` is `double` and `3.0` is also `double`. The `double` type has about 16 decimal digits precision. In the second program the `float` is promoted to `double` for the variadic function but does not magically gain more precision.

From C11 § 6.4.4.2

> 4 An unsuffixed floating constant has **type double**. If suffixed by the letter f or F, it has type float. If suffixed by the letter l or L, it has type long double.

and C11 § 6.5.2.2

> 6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and **arguments that have type float are promoted to double**.
>
> 7 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type. The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. **The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments**.

Answer (score 1):

**Only if** the precision was missing, it would have been taken as 6. Otherwise, if you specify the precision, it's going to honor that.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 7.21.6.1/P8, (*emphasis mine*)

> `f,F`
> A double argument representing a floating-point number is converted to decimal notation in the style [-]ddd.ddd, **where the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification. If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6;** [...]

Comment: ...but note that printing more digits does not make it more precise. There is a limit to what a floating point variable can represent.

Comment: IMO that's not what the question is asking, but the reason why the outputs are `66.666666666667` and `66.666664123535`, where OP thinks they should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

In most C implementations, `float` and `double` do not use decimal digits. They use binary.

In the first program, `3.0` is a `double`, so `s/3.0` is computed with `double` arithmetic. In spite of `f` being the initial letter of `float`, `%.12f` takes a `double` argument, for reasons involving the history of C development. So the `double` value `s/3.0` is converted to decimal with 12 digits after the decimal point and printed.

In the second program, `s` is a `float`, so `s/3` is computed with `float` arithmetic. In the format you use, the result is a binary-based number, 8738133 • 2<sup>−17</sup>. The reason there are many decimal digits involved is that, while expressing 2<sup>−17</sup> is simple using that base of 2, in decimal it is 0.00000762939453125. then 8738133 times that is 66.66666412353515625. Since you asked for only 12 digits, you see 66.6666641235. (Note: The `float` value is converted to `double` to be passed to `printf`, but this does not change the value.)